# evaluate system command or python script in firefox browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, linux, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

May be duplicate.

I would like to write javascript which can execute linux command in firefox (seems to be impossible but asking with hope)

from googling, found that it is possible for IE through "ActiveXObject".

here is sample code:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function executeCommands(inputparms)
   {
  // Instantiate the Shell object and invoke 
   its execute method.

    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

    var commandtoRun = "C:\\Winnt\\Notepad.exe";
    if (inputparms != "")
     {
      var commandParms = document.Form1.filename.value;
     }

 // Invoke the execute method.  
     oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, commandParms, 
      "", "open", "1");
  }
</SCRIPT>
```

So, Is there any equivalent of ActiveXObject in javascript for mozilla apps?
I'm quite new to javascript so please, correct mistakes if any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Firefox add-on you can use [nsIProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess). Something along these lines:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                     .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("C:\\Winnt\\Notepad.exe");
var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
              .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(file);
process.runAsync(["c:\\file.txt"]);
```

This API is only accessible to privileged code of course.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have tried your code on Ubuntu with file path changes. but it gives an error:

[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath]"  nsresult: "0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://helloworld/content/overlay.js :: anonymous :: line 85"  data: no]

Comment: @Yajushi: You should use an absolute path like `"/usr/bin/sh"`, relative paths or paths using backslashes will be rejected with this error message.

Comment: Thanks again. It's working.
just need your help again, if you can.

Code works for "/usr/bin/openoffice.org" and "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal" but when I tried for "/usr/bin/onboard" it opens nothing..
any idea, what is wrong ?

Comment: It seems that only binary executable files are working , not simple sh executable files.

Comment: @Yajushi: That's very well possible, Gecko starts the process directly rather than using the shell. So for shell scripts you would need to run `/usr/bin/sh` with with `["-c", "/path/to/script"]` as parameters.

Comment: No luck, I still can't launch the script.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to run arbitrary, native commands on the client's machine.